How can I adjust font size in a QGIS print-layout PDF export?
I want to create a pdf-map in QGIS (3.16 and 3.34).
As explained in this answer
(Adjusting font size of map labels in QGIS print layouts) I adjusted the font size of the labels in a polygon-shape in the main map and started the layout-window. The label size is fine there, but when I export it as a pdf (QGIS function) and open it, the labels are (too) small. It doesn't change even if I triple my font size in the main map.
The symbology in the point-layer works fine. I also had to enlarge it. Now it's big enough.
My (layer) labels settings that are not working in the pdf are the following:
It's a composed single label ("NUMBER" || ' ' || "NAME"); stil "normal"; size in points.
Edit: I tried the label size in points, millimeter, map units and pixel; it doesn't make any difference.

Please include relevant information, like your label settings, in your question.

Do you mean these? I added: "It's a composed single label ("NUMBER" || ' ' || "NAME"); stil "normal"; size in dots."
Or do you need further informations?

Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would help for them to need to sift through comments to understand the Question.

Sorry, I don't get exactly, what you mean @Vince since I'd already add the label settings in my main post. Now I've edited the title question and hope that I could clarify my request.

What units are you using in you label size?  The setting is in the drop down below the font size setting in the label form.  The default is usually points, you might want to try different values for some of the others and see how that works.
